# Latency playing audio with AudioTrack from hash map after clicking button

Tags: android, audio, latency, audiotrack, audiorecord

I know Android is known for having audio latency issues but I have done everything I know of to reduce it and I still have noticeable latency in my music application between pressing the button and hearing the sound.

I first made the app using MediaPlayer which was way too slow so I switched to SoundPool but that was still to slow. So I had to go much lower level and use AudioRecord and AudioTrack to record and play raw PCM audio data. I store the raw audio data in a hash map related to a file name. I also make a WAV file for permanent storage but I'm not actually playing the audio from that. I have even tried chunking the audio data when I send it to the AudioTrack object with AudioTrack.write and have tried many different chunk sizes, settling on 1024 for now. I create one AudioTrack object instance per button and keep alive for that button for the life cycle of the app and just reuse it. This way there is a separate thread and AudioTrack object handling the playback for all the different sounds. I also switched to using onTouch ACTION_DOWN to trigger rather than onClick. Nothing seems to help much.

Even then I still have noticeable lag. Haven't measured it yet but it seems like it's around 300ms or so. Definitely better than with SoundPool but still not usable for a live music making application. The app plays drum beats with recorded sounds so it has to be almost instantaneous or it's useless.

I know it's possible to make a live music making android app with very low latency because I have apps that do that like Mini Piano Lite, Caustic etc.

[Here's the class that handles the audio](https://github.com/AlteriusOmega/BeatCube/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/therealsamchaney/beatcube/Recorder.java) and below is the most relevant method that actually plays the sound.

```
public static void recordPlay(String fileName) {
    Log.d("AudioTrack", "in recordPlay fileName " + fileName);
    byte[] bytes = soundNameDataHashMap.get(fileName); // Get the data from the hashmap based on file name

    if (bytes != null) { // There is audio data for this file name
        Log.d("AudioTrack", "in recordPlay bytes was not null, fileName " + fileName);

        // Check if there is an AudioTrack for this fileName
        AudioTrack audioTrack = soundNameAudioTrackHashMap.get(fileName);
        if (audioTrack == null){
            // If there isn't one yet, make one
            audioTrack = createAudioTrack();
            soundNameAudioTrackHashMap.put(fileName, audioTrack); // Add the new AudioTrack to the hash map for this file name
        } else {
            // If there is an existing one, we just need to stop it to get ready to play again
            // Check if it's playing currently
            if (audioTrack.getPlayState() == AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING){ // TODO this check is only necessary when chunking the audioTrack.write below which doesn't even really seem to help
                audioTrack.stop();
                audioTrack.flush();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        // Play the AudioTrack and write the data to it
        Log.d("recordPlay", "recordPlay: right before audioTrack.play()!");
        audioTrack.play();
        Log.d("recordPlay", "recordPlay: right before audioTrack.write(bytes)!");

        int chunkSize = 1024; // 1024 seems good
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i += chunkSize){
            int blockSize = Math.min(chunkSize, bytes.length - i);
            audioTrack.write(bytes, i, blockSize);
        }
        Log.d("recordPlay", "recordPlay: At the end of recordPlay!");
    } else {
        Log.d("AudioTrack", "No sound recorded on that button yet!");
    }
}
```